# How I can get a value from a text file and select a checkbox who have that value?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

How I can get a value from a text file and select a checkbox who have that value ?

I tried with this code to get the value who is after equal:

```
string installerfilename = string.Format("{0}{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "installer.ini");
            IEnumerable<string> inilines = File.ReadAllLines(installerfilename).AsEnumerable();

            string selectedItem = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            bool IsChecked = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains(selectedItem);
    inlines = inlines.Select(line => line == string.Format("‪product‬={0}", selectedItem))
                    ? Regex.Replace(line, string.Format("product={0}", selectedItem), string.Format(@"product={0}", selectedItem)) : line);
```

also I tried with this :

```
foreach (var line in inilines)
            {
                if (line.Contains("product={0}"))
                {
                    IsChecked = true;
                    //checkedListBox1.CheckedItems =true;
                }
```

but I don't know how to check the box from a CheckedListBox who have the value after equal for the rows how are like `product="name of checkbox"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Test.txt");

lines.ToList()
     .ForEach(item =>
     {
         //check if item exists in CheckedListBox set it checked.
         //We find the index of the item, -1 means that item doesn't exists in CheckedListBox
         var index = this.checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item);
         if(index >=0)
             this.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
     });
```

**Note:**

- Instead of using a file for saving and restoring your checked items, It's better to use a settings property to save your checked items.

**Check all Items:**

To check an item by its index, yo ucan use `this.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);`, so for checking all items, you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    this.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

**For your specific case:**

you have a file containing:

```
product=item1
#product=item2
#product=item3
product=item4
```

That means item1 and item4 should be checked, you can use `Where` and `Select` to select what you need from lines, for example:

```
lines.Where(x=>!x.StartsWith("#"))
     .Select(x=>x.Replace("Product=","").Trim())
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(item =>
     {
         var index = this.checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item);
         if(index >=0)
             this.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
     });
```

Comment: and how I can make, when in text file I have product= all to select all check boxes ?

Comment: @ben Simply check first line, if the first line is all, call SetItemChecked for all indexes

Comment: @ben but I instead of saving "all" its better to save checked items.

Comment: I tried to use this code but I have next error : "Operator >= cannot be applied to operands of type "string and int.

Comment: @ben oops. that was a typo! I edited the code, that was index.

Comment: @ben at that line, we are checking if that line of file is one of CheckedListBox  items.

Comment: In my case that value was not found because I have the value after = in my text file I have "product=name of checkbox "

Comment: @ben You can remove `Product=` from each line simply :) , but the important thing is the main technique that used read items and check them in checkedlisbox.

Comment: and how I can add a condition, where I have # before product=name that checkbox to not be checked?

Comment: @ben using  `Where` method:)

Comment: @ben for additional question it's better to ask a new question, and also feel free to kindly accept this answer to be more useful for future readers.

Comment: The last thing... in your post you say I want  item1 and item2 to be checked, but I want to say item1 and item4 should be check and item2 and item3 to be uncheck

Comment: @ben again a typo ;) item1 and item4 will be checked :)

Comment: sorry but in this case I don't know way when I run the program the checkboxes remain unchecked :(

Comment: @ben I recommend you keep this Q/A clean. And ask a new question for your specific case. Ask a question and put a sample content of your file and say what you need :)

Comment: and if I tried to check a box I have the next message : "InvalidArgument=Value of'-1' is not valide for index

Comment: @ben I think the information in this answer is enough to solve such problem, but if you think you need more hellp in your specific case, I think too keep this Q/A more clean and I think it's better to ask a new question and post content of your file and describe your specific case, I'll help you If I see your question :)